# How to configure a jump server to allow access to a local server web GUI from a remote client machine?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, remote-access, ssh-tunnel

I have an EVE-NG VM running in ESXi at my house for building network topologies in a lab environment. I would like to be able to access this VM from outside the local network without using my router to do the port forwarding, as it’s proven to be ineffective. I spun up a Ubuntu VM on the same physical machine as a jump server but I’m not very experienced with Linux yet (very excited to learn though). What do I need to do on the EVE-NG VM itself, if anything, and how do I configure the Ubuntu server, in order to use SSH tunneling to access the EVE VM web interface remotely?

Comment: You'd use a proxy connect command with a tunnel command - I'm unsure what the `ssh` command parameter is, but for PuTTY it's done using `plink` with two PuTTY profiles, the 2nd destination that occurs via the multi-hop and the 1st destination of the server initiating the multi-hop: `plink -v -load <Remote Profile> -nc %host:%port`, where `<Remote Profile>` is the 1st SSH server the multi-hop is passing through. To access a WebUI, it would be tunneled through the 2nd destination's profile settings via `L<local port #> 127.0.0.1:<WebUI port #>` _([example](https://i.imgur.com/80GY52x.png))_